# Protractor reload a page when it's crashed

Tags: angularjs, protractor, wait, sleep

Let me explain the situation, I'm currently testing an AngularJS website with Protractor, I'm not developing it at all.

The problem is that, absolutely randomly the website is sometime not rendered. It's just blank with a different title :

- If title is "VideoGame" -> then website is rendered
- If title is "VideoGame-env-DEV" -> Then the website isn't rendered

No idea why and it's not my concern.

However, when testing with Protractor, it's obviously crashing.

So I wanted to bypass the problem with a temporary solution :

```
    function specialRefreshFunction() {

    cpt=0;
    browser.get('https://blablabla');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    var title = browser.getTitle();
    while (title != "VideoGame") {
        cpt=cpt+1;
        //sleep(1000);
        //browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.get('https://blablabla');
        browser.waitForAngular();
        //browser.navigate().refresh();
        console.log("fail  "+cpt);
    }

    console.log("Correct title  " + title);}
```

My solution isn't working. I'm a total newbie with NodeJS & Protractor, so the code might be a nonsense.

- W10 64bits
- Latest Chromedriver
- Protractor 5.4.2
- NodeJS 10.15.0
- Angular 6.1.10

Thank you !

Comment: At first glance, it's easy to ask the question 'What's the point of automation testing on a site if your automation test is going to be made to pass when the site doesn't even render?' -- but you'd be surprised how often this comes up in the industry.  There are a variety of reasons why you might want to refresh and retry without failing, if a known issue is preventing your script from getting into the functionality you actually want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `browser.wait`

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(
    EC.presenceOf($('#some-element')),
    10000,
    'Element did not appear after route change'
).then(function() {}, function() {
    browser.refresh();
});
```

In this particular example protractor will wait 10 sec for element `#some-element` to appear on the page. `browser.wait` returns a promise, so you can handle both cases - when element appear or element did not appear. Just put some specific selector instead of `$('#some-element')` that present on your page, by which you can consider page as loaded

Though, if you rely only on title value, you can use [`titleContains`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.titleContains)

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the title to contain 'foo'.
browser.wait(EC.titleContains('foo'), 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you, however with the following code, the page isn't refreshing : `function specialRefreshFunction() {
        //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(url);
        let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(
            EC.titleIs("VideoGame"), 500,"Incorrect").
        then(function() {}, function() {
            browser.refresh();
            console.log("Reload");
        });
        //browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    }`

If I uncomment the ignoreSynchronization, it works randomly.

Comment: first of all, `ignoreSynchronization ` is deprecated in latest protractor, use `waitForAngularEnabled ` instead, secondary, why do you even need this? you told that you have an angularjs application

Comment: after all, you give `specialRefreshFunction` implementation, but did not give an usage example, how and when you call this func?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom promise like that:

```
public vierifyPageTitle() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const refreshUserData = setInterval(() => {
            return browser.getTitle().then((title) => {
                if (title === 'VideoGame') {
                    clearInterval(refreshUserData);
                    resolve(title);
                }
            }, (err) => {
                browser.refresh();
                reject(err);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

It's refreshing every 1000 ms if title is not equal to expected.